# Horizontal Scroll is working vertically

Tags: android, android-studio

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2mbug.jpg)

```
public class PostAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    public LayoutInflater inflater;
    public ArrayList<Bitmap> data=new ArrayList<Bitmap>();
    public int layout;
    public PostAdapter(Context c, int layout, ArrayList<Bitmap> data){
        this.inflater=(LayoutInflater)c.getSystemService(c.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        this.data=data;
        this.layout=layout;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return data.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if(convertView==null){

            convertView=inflater.inflate(layout,parent,false);
        }
        Bitmap bm=data.get(position);
        ImageView addList_picture=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.addlist_picture);
        addList_picture.setImageBitmap(bm);

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

### -> adapter code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/addlist_picture"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        app:srcCompat="@color/common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_disabled" />
</LinearLayout>
```

### -> each items layout

```
<HorizontalScrollView
            android:id="@+id/h_scroll_picture"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:fillViewport="true">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
                <ListView
                    android:id="@+id/h_scroll_listView"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    <!--android:listSelector="#39000000"-->
                </ListView>
            </LinearLayout>
        </HorizontalScrollView>
```

-> scrollView layout

---

```
image_uri=data.getData();
            try {
                // add one bitmap
                item.add(MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(),image_uri));

                // adapter refresh
                postAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

-> main java

I want to locate lists horizontally. but they are still vertical.
Bitmap datas are well applied in the list.
Could you hell me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For horizontal Scroll, use Recycler view instead of Listview.

Set the layout manager to horizontal. Use the below code

```
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager
    = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);

RecyclerView myList = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
myList.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```

Or if you want to use Listview ,you will need to use a library like:

```
com.meetme.android.horizontallistview.HorizontalListView
```

This will make your task simpler

Please refer:

```
https://github.com/MeetMe/Android-HorizontalListView
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: oh, your anwers is very helpful for me. I appriciate you!